# Call Tumblr API from within a custom theme

Tags: javascript, api, themes, tumblr

I'm writing a custom tumblr theme for a client who needs to use the platform.

The functionality required goes beyond that offered by the Custom Theme tags, so I need to incorporate API calls to add an improved experience.

I'm a fairly experienced developer but totally new to Tumblr. Is there a way I can make calls to their API from within my theme without requiring OAuth callbacks?

Currently my theme comprises of a HTML file and an external JS file that does a whole bunch of other things (Non-Ajax type stuff).

Ideally somewhat like the following:

```
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/fdsfdsf.tumblr.com/posts', true);
  request.onerror = _handleError;
  request.onload = _handleResponse;
  request.send();
```

Comment: Register a new app and use your app public API key, you can register at http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/apps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Helped partially by @Adam's response. My final solution was to create an app here [tumblr.com/oauth/apps](https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/apps) and then use my consumer key in my API requests as such:

`http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/<MY_BLOG>/posts/photo?api_key=<MY_KEY>&jsonp=callback"` and use JSONP to handle the `callback` function.

My final code:

```
var apiKey = "gdfgdfgdfgdsfgdfhgsdfghsfdh";
var requestURL = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/dfsdf.tumblr.com/posts/photo?api_key=" + apiKey + "&jsonp=callback";

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = requestURL;

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
// or document.head.appendChild(script) in modern browsers

window.callback = function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's the way to go! Thanks for posting your solution.

Comment: This is pretty powerful... now you have access to the entire API in your theme, instead of just the things the Theme API makes available.

Mind dropping a hint as to what you're going to do with this?

Comment: @Cyrin Yep, I built a theme for RayBan's brand Persol using this technique http://persol.tumblr.com/